# Script to check mosquitto is healthy

Tags: bash, docker, mosquitto

I'm trying to create a health check script for mosquitto (to be used by docker).

```
if [ -z "$USERNAME" ]; then
 mosquitto_sub -t '$SYS/#' -C 1 | grep -v Error || exit 1
else 
 mosquitto_sub -t '$SYS/#' -C 1 -u $USERNAME -P $PASSWRD | grep -v Error || exit 1
fi
```

The issue I'm having is that if an incorrect password is given mosquitto_sub just keeps outputting  `Connection Refused: not authorised.` over and over, and the timeout stuff in docker appears flakey, so it just never ends.

It doesn't look like mosquitto gives any way to fail better. I think I might need to execute it as a background process that I can kill, but my bash isn't really that great, so does anyone have any better ideas?

[EDIT - updated as per BMitch's suggestion]

I have modified the script to look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$USERNAME" ]; then
        (sleep 10; kill $$) & exec mosquitto_sub -t '$SYS/#' -C 1 | grep -v Error || exit 1 "$@"
else
        (sleep 10; kill $$) & exec mosquitto_sub -t '$SYS/#' -u $USERNAME -P $PASSWORD -C 1 | grep -v Error || exit 1  "$@"
fi
```

but running it just gives the following output:

```
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Terminated
root@e30e9cadd8fc:/# Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
Connection Refused: not authorised.
```

Answer (score 1):

(changed idea of [BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596285/bmitch))

I had to change the timeout argument from `--foreground` to `-t` and escape the `$` by putting one more `$` sign before it.

In my docker-compose it look next(*keep in mind that username and password are removed, you still can add them - just escape the `$` sign again*):

`version: '3'
services:
  mosquitto:
    image: 'eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.7'
    container_name: mosquitto
    hostname: mosquitto
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - ./mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
      - ./mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config
    networks:
      - cluster
    restart: on-failure
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "timeout -t 5 mosquitto_sub -t '$$SYS/#' -C 1 | grep -v Error || exit 1"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 6`

Comment: It's not working. I am getting this error:
 Output": "Connection error: Connection Refused: not authorised.\n"

Answer (score 0):

There's a [bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068) on how to timeout your running script. Try replacing mosquitto_sub with a mosquitto_sub_timeout.sh that contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
(sleep 10; kill $$) & exec mosquitto_sub "$@"
```

Then your healthcheck script will look like:

```
if [ -z "$USERNAME" ]; then
 mosquitto_sub_timeout.sh -t '$SYS/#' -C 1 | grep -v Error || exit 1
else 
 mosquitto_sub_timeout.sh -t '$SYS/#' -C 1 -u $USERNAME -P $PASSWRD | grep -v Error || exit 1
fi
```

---

And one last update, as mentioned in the bash FAQ, the timeout command may be the best solution of them all as long as it's installed in your container:

```
if [ -z "$USERNAME" ]; then
 timeout --foreground 10 mosquitto_sub -t '$SYS/#' -C 1 | grep -v Error || exit 1
else 
 timeout --foreground 10 mosquitto_sub -t '$SYS/#' -C 1 -u $USERNAME -P $PASSWRD | grep -v Error || exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. I put that at the top, but it still just says connection refused until I eventually ctrl+c it.

Comment: Likely because `mosquitto_sub` is going to be a separate process that isn't being killed by the signal to the parent shell, I'll tweak the answer with a potential workaround, but the bash FAQ is much more thorough.

Comment: That didn't work - I've updated the original question to reflect the changes I made. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The second shell script that contains an exec separate from your parent shell script is important. Otherwise the exec will break your grep and other commands. The separate terminated error leads me to think it's spawning other commands and you may need a `killall mosquitto_xyz` for some other command being launched that's holding open the tty.

Comment: I've also updated with the timeout command that will likely be better than any bash script option.

Answer (score 0):

`mosquitto_sub` has its own, internal timeout that I think should be sufficient and better. From https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1270#issuecomment-1476038461:

```yaml
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mosquitto_sub", "-t", "$$SYS/#", "-C", "1", "-i", "healthcheck", "-W", "3"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 20s
```

> "-W 3": timeout after 3 seconds if not recieved any message

https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1270#issuecomment-1478648748