# Docker-compose health check for Mosquitto

Tags: mosquitto

I setup mosquitto password using a password file

```
volumes:
  - /password:/mosquitto/config
```

How can I add healthcheck in docker-compose? I tried the below solution provided here
[Script to check mosquitto is healthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275666/script-to-check-mosquitto-is-healthy)

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "timeout -t 5 mosquitto_sub -t '$$SYS/#' -C 1 | grep -v Error || exit 1"]
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 6
```

Also, I tried a couple of other options but they are asking me to pass username and password. Can't I use this password file?

update:
mosquitto.conf

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /mosquitto/config/pwfile
port 1883
listener 9001
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a push you could enable listener with  MQTT over Websockets as the protocol and then use a basic curl get request to check it the broker is up.

e.g. add this to the mosquitto.conf

```
listener 8080 127.0.0.1
protocol websockets
```

and a health check something like

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080" ]
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 6
```

The raw HTTP GET request should complete without needing to authenticate.

The other option is re-enable anonymous users and to add readonly access to the anonymous user to access the `$SYS/#` topic pattern using a acl file ([acl_file](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm44))

Comment: Updated my question. I am already using mosquitto.conf file.

Comment: Nothing to stop you adding extra to your existing config file. (and I don't see any edits to the question)

Comment: Sorry. Edited now.

Comment: Everything I've said still applies, that mosquitto.conf just runs 2 native MQTT listeners 1883 and 9001 (you've not set a protocol on any of them) and there is nothing to stop you adding another listener bound to 127.0.0.1 just for the healthcheck

Comment: Tired but getting 
"Output": "curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer\n"

Comment: Add `"-X",  "Upgrade"` to the array of CMD arguments before the url

Comment: Just one last thing. It working when I add: protocol websockets
but if I remove this line I am getting 
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer\n"

Is there any way, I can make it work with adding protocol websockets. Dev is not ready for me to add web socket

Comment: Of course it needs websockets, that is the only way mosquitto will respond to a HTTP request. The extra listener is bound to `127.0.0.1` so it can only be accessed by the healthcheck command. If/When you want to add websocket support you can add another listener on a different port with `protocol websockets` bound to all interfaces then you can use that for messaging.

Comment: Now it's clear to me. thanks for the clarification